# Using a JavaScript function in an HTML <area> to play audio on click

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to get this to work so that if the user clicks on the specified area, then a sound plays (without changing what is showed on the screen at all).  Right now I'm using an image of a keyboard with a `<map>` with `<area>` tags corresponding to the keys of the keyboard.  I've made `<area>` tags for three of the keys so far, using different methods of trying to get the sound to play on click, but none of them seem to work.  If possible, I would like to be able to use a JavaScript function to get this working, like I've attempted with the first two keyboard keys.

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function playSound(soundfile) {
     var audio = new Audio("+soundfile+");
     audio.play();
   }
</script>

<body>

<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/PianoKeyboard.svg/250px-PianoKeyboard.svg.png" width="500" height="300" alt="keyboard" usemap="#keyMap">

<map name="keyMap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,200,72,300" alt="C" href="JavaScript: playSound('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg');">
   <area shape="rect" coords="72,200,144,300" alt="D" href="#" onclick=playSound('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg')>
   <area shape="rect" coords="144,200,216,300" alt="E" href="#audio">
</map>

<audio src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did everything well. And first 2 cases works good. Just small error: remove quotes from function:

```
 function playSound(soundfile) {
     var audio = new Audio(soundfile);
     audio.play();
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3c68/